# How does the spindle fiber find the kinetochore?

Tags: meiosis, mitosis

I am curious if anyone knows the exact mechanism of how exactly does the spindle fiber find the kinetochore? it certainly seems like a fairly non-spontaneous reaction for a spindle fiber to reach all the way to a chromosome, how are these type of reactions carried out without producing new proteins? How Can cells execute complex "choreography" such as mitosis without making new proteins on the spot?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but don't assume that the requisite proteins are not already available or cannot be made.

Comment: But here is my confusion, we learned about the signal transduction pathway and the central dogma of molecular biology as the basis for how life exists, if DNA is bundled up into chromosomes during cell division, then how do we carry out such a complicated process ? to me its like cell division implies that gene expression isnt needed for cells to carry out complex tasks...which is crazy...You figure that  especially in the context of evolution mitosis is when a cell needs to be most responsive to problems and stimuli, you dont want your plane on "auto-pilot" when it is about to land...